# How to implement inactivity and refresh jwt token in NextAuth

Tags: next.js, jwt, next-auth

Im using NextJs 14 with NextAuth JWT and my token is expiring in 30 min, but i want to implement both or one of this 2 strategies:

Inactivity: If the user stay 5 min without do anything on the website, the token should expire before the expiration time.

Refresh: If the user do any action after 29 min loggedIn, if the token expires it should not redirect the user to login page, instead it should just refresh the token and give the user more 30 min.

How can i do that in nextjs? The seccond one is more useful for me, but both is good.

Anyone knows how to do that?